# Horse has two legs about

Tags: sentence-usage

Someone asked me what if horse had two legs how would it be look like?

I replied if horse had two legs then it would have been looked like same as you.

I just want to know in that reply am I grammatically correct or not?

Comment: Please add more detail to explain what specifically is the confusing grammar?  Otherwise this question will be closed as "proofreading".

Comment: *it would have been looked like same as you* is syntactic garbage on many levels.

Comment: The verb **look** is not transitive in the sense of "appear", and so you're forming an invalid passive construction with **have been looked**.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not correct.

Whenever you use continuous tenses, such as the present continuous (*is looking*), the past continuous (*was looking*), and the past perfect continuous (*had been looking*), a [gerund](https://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/gerund/) is always required.

Instead, in replies like this, the present [conditional](https://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/conditional/) is the best option:

> If a horse had two legs, **it would look** the same as you.

Comment: But what if I said "would have been looked like" what would it signifies?

Comment: @fusion _have been looked_ does not exist as a verb tense because you're combining a past participle (_looked_) with continuous tenses that require a gerund (_looking_).